Zeros of two equations
Consider the equations
$$ 
1+\frac{1}{z^k}=0 \quad\mbox{and}\quad 1+\frac{1}{z^k}+\frac{1}{(z+1)^k}=0,
$$
where $k$ is a positive integer $\ge 4$. I would like to show for instance that the number of zeros in $\frac{\pi}{2}\lt \mbox{Arg}(z) \lt \frac{2\pi}{3}$ is the same for both equations. I'm not sure if this is true, I'm basing this on numerical evidence.
Of course the first equation is equivalent to $z^k=-1$, so all the zeros lie on the unit circle and it is easy to explicitely compute the zeros. The problem is with the second equation, there can be some zeros outside the unit circle, so the condition $\frac{\pi}{2}\lt \mbox{Arg}(z) \lt \frac{2\pi}{3}$ is really important here. Intuitively what I think happens is that in this region the term $1/(z+1)^k$ is small for big $k$, but when $\mbox{Arg}(z)$ is close to $2\pi/3$ this is not always the case (in that case $|1/(z+1)^k|\approx 1$, so it does contribute to the second equation).
Is there a way to get past the issue near $2\pi/3$ and show that the two equations have the same number of zeros and moreover the solutions are close to each other? (Again this is from numerical evidence)

Wolfram alpha is saying that there are different number of solutions for $k=8,10$ in the sector $\frac{\pi}{2}< Arg(z) < \frac{2\pi}{3}$ for both the equations. @Itachi

See roots of equation 2 and roots of equation 1.

The obvious conjecture here, nicely illustrated in @sam 's answer, is that the roots of the second equation seem to lie on or near the perimeter of the union of the unit circles centred at $0$ and $-1$, and the portion of the line $\text{Re}(z)=-\frac12$ that lies in their interior.

@Sam you are absolutely right, I was only considering multiples of 12 as values for $k$.

@ChrisLewis I like that conjecture, and it does explain what I wanted to know. In the region that I'm interested, the solutions are very close to each other with the exception of the line Re$(z)=-\frac{1}{2}$. I think now the way to prove this is show that when we the argument of $z$ is away from $2\pi/3$, the function $1/(z+1)^k$ decreases exponentially with $k$, and then maybe use Rouché's theorem in some way

The two equations don't have the same number of solution in the given sector for every $k$. Define $(I)$ as equation $z^k+1=0$ and $(II)$ as equation $(1+z^k)(1+z)^k+z^k=0$. For $k=8$, numerically $(I)$ has $1$ solutions and $(II)$ has no solutions in sector $\frac{\pi}{2} < \text{Arg}(z) < \frac{2\pi}{3}$. If you denote $N_1,N_2$ as the solutions of $(I),(II)$ respectively in the given sector, then for $k\le 50$, (all of them are even :o )
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\hline 
         k&  N_1& N_2\\ \hline
         8&  1& 0\\ \hline 
         10&  0& 1\\ \hline 
         14&  1& 0\\ \hline 
         18&  1& 2\\ \hline 
         20&  2& 1\\ \hline 
         32&  3& 2\\ \hline 
         34&  2& 3\\ \hline 
         38&  3& 2\\ \hline 
         42&  3& 4\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$
Now coming to magnitude of the solutions, all solutions to the right of $x=-1/2$ line are indeed close to each other. This is illustrated in the image below for $k=195$.

Addendum: The following matlab code was used to produce this image, it only works till $k=195$:
syms z
k = 195
eqn1 = z^k==-1;
eqn2 = (z^k+1)*(1+1/z)^k == -1;
%Solve both the equations 
Root1=vpasolve(eqn1);  Root2=vpasolve(eqn2);
figure; 
%Scatter plot the solutions
scatter(real(Root1),imag(Root1),38,"filled")
hold on
scatter(real(Root2),imag(Root2),28,"filled")
%Real and imaginary axis
xline(0); yline(0);
[n1,m1] = size(Root1);
%Make lines connecting root to origin 
for j=1:n1
line([0 real(Root1(j))],[0 imag(Root1(j))])
end
[n2,m2] = size(Root2);
for j=1:n2
line([0 real(Root2(j))],[0 imag(Root2(j))],'Color','red')
end
hold off
axis equal
title("k="+num2str(k))
legend("eq1","eq2")

Observe that some zeroes of equation $II$ are vertically stacked near the vertical line $x=-1/2$. This is also observed for smaller values of $k$,


How are you computing these solutions? If you look at the left hand side of your plot, it's clear to see the roots do not occur in conjugate pairs. But your equation has real coefficients, so this can't be correct.

@ChrisLewis Added the code for clarity. I am Using matlab sym box to compute the solutions

Thanks. But as I mentioned, you can see there is a problem with the roots it's producing. I suspect you're quite far outside the numerical capabilities of MATLAB when you have a polynomial of degree $394$.

yes you are right, something is amiss @ChrisLewis The code does return 394 solutions, but a lot of them are not conjugates

I've been trying a bit with MATLAB too (not vpasolve, just Newton Raphson) and running into some problems even with lower degrees. It seems quite sensitive numerically. Ah, I see you've edited your answer (it now kind of says the opposite of what you were saying before, but the plot you have is similar to what I'm finding)

Yeah @ChrisLewis Surprisingly the solutions of both the equations are now stacked on top of each other in the given sector, didn't see that coming.

Thank you very much, I'm very satisfied with the answer and it gave me some insight in what to do next.
